# How to use ec2 instance as personal dev box using intellij as IDE?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2, x11, xterm

I have searched the questions and have not found an answer to this one:

I am developing an existing project (git repo) that runs only on Linux. For the time being I have at my disposal only a windows laptop which I cannot modify. This laptop has Intellij installed and internet access. I cannot, for example, create a Linux VM on this laptop.

Is there a way I can put the project code on an Amazon ec2 Linux instance and build the project on that instance, while viewing and developing the code in Intellij? All compilation and code execution has to be done remotely, on the ec2 Linux instance. I cannot build locally and push from the windows laptop.

2 possible configurations might be: 
(1) install intellij on the ec2 instance and x-window in from windows to view the intellij screens;
(2) use the intellij on the Windows laptop and somehow point the intellij to the ec2 instance in order to view, edit, build, and run the project on that instance.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Intellij has support for [remote deubgging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-remote.html?origin=old_help&search=remote).

Comment: Thanks, Burhan, I looked at Run/Debug/Remote and it looks promising. Can you not only run on the remote JVM, but view, and make changes to, the remote source code?

Answer (score 1):

ec2 with enough memory for development is billed / hour. For 32gb RAM it's >$80/month (always online ~450h).

You could use wls 2 under windows. You can install IDEA and use it trough X server like
VcXsrv and access to windows files. It's not the best idea to run full GNOME (even xfce4). Google chrome also works very well

Downsides are:

- (still) slow access to drive compared to raw Linux
- I cannot configure WSL to access same VPN as in Windows. It simply cuts off internet connection for WSL while I click `connect` in windows.